# Printing serial number in jasper report detail

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created a jasper report. In that report in detail areaI have "serialNumber" column. That column wants to be auto incrementive and stats with "1". I am using `hibernate` for query.
Sample code is :

```xml
<detail>
    <band height="17" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement x="12" y="0" width="27" height="15"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[serialNumber]]>
            </textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="51" y="0" width="37" height="15"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{date}]]>
            </textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="138" y="0" width="75" height="15"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{time}]]>
            </textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Can anyone help to print serial number in jasper report.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using variable we can achieve that.

Sample code :

```
 <variable name="seraialNumber" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="None" 
calculation="Count"/>
```

Depends on the requirement we have to change expression

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind the column to a bean which returns incrementing numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You Can use alternate solution for this problem that build in Variable $V{REPORT_COUNT}.

This variable will return the row count in Integer format.

Sample Expression :

```
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<variable name="serial number" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Column" calculation="Count">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[0]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
```

I will show an image for better understanding[image]